# Detect an elite proxy

Tags: proxy

How can i detect an elite proxy?
it's ok if i don't get them all, since it won't be possible
but atleast most of them?

Comment: not really a programming question.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities that should require more than one destination (most web browsing) yet constantly show up as the same destination are a good indicator of a proxy.

If a single site accounts for more than 20-30% of a user's request, it might be worth looking into to see if that is a proxy or not. This should mean you'd only ever manually investigate 2 or 3 sites per user. You can adjust this threshold as convenient.

For sure, you need solid logging for your network environment.